# How to get the value of a cms:FormField in a form layout script block?

Tags: kentico

I have a form that has a layout like so:

```
<cms:FormField runat="server" ID="fMemberType" Field="MemberType" />
<cms:FormField runat="server" ID="fEmployeeCount" Field="EmployeeCount" />

<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="test" Text="test" />

<script runat="server">
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  test.Text = fMemberType.Value.ToString();
}
</script>
```

However this produces `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` because it can't find `fMemberType` for some reason. Looking for the correct way of doing this.

It's worth noting that the form fields are dropdowns with depending flags set so changing them triggers a postback, or at least it would, but I set the webpart container to be an update panel so it's AJAXing which means the data isn't available in the page POST params. I could turn this off and grab the data from the POST data but wanted to know if there was a better way first.

Comment: Can you share the definition of these form fields?

Comment: What do you want to know about them?

Comment: Are you sure fMemberType is null and not Value? 

Try:
`test.Text = CMS.Helper.ValidationHelper.GetString(fMemberType.Value,"default")`

What is the test literal text then?

Answer (score 0):

So you're fully defining the fields and everything for your form?  Why not use the DataForm control and dynamically create the form for you?  You can then get the data like so: (formUserSettings is a cms:DataForm)

```
EditingFormControl ctrState = formUserSettings.BasicForm.FieldEditingControls["UserState"] as EditingFormControl;
```

Then do some checking and assign the value:

```
if (ctrState != null)
{
    fState = ctrlState.Value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the form value is not set until after the pre-render.  Alen Genzic's recommendation will show that.  May want to try OnInit.